# Calendar provider doesn't support RSCALE element of the RRULE field

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentprovider

I am working for a startup company and they want to develop an android calendar application that supports non-Gregorian events.  I followed ical standard based on this [reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7529). It's recommended using `RSCALE` element inside `RRULE` field to create recurrent events for non-Gregorian Calendars. For example the following represents the Chinese new year event

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20130210
   RRULE:RSCALE=CHINESE;FREQ=YEARLY
```

The issue is raised when I want to store such kinds of events in the `Calendar Provider`. So I face with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid recurrence rule: RSCALE=CHINESE;FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1
```

So it seems `Calendar provider` doesn't support `RSCALE`. Now, what should I do to store such kinds of events?

Comment: What is your code for the "store such kinds of events" part? IOW, how are you using this iCal string?

Comment: I use "contentresolver" to insert content values in the calendar provider and I put a string value for the "rrule" , for example "put(Events.RRULE, rrule)" where "rrule" is "RSCALE=CHINESE;FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1".